# How to scroll down to click the element in Android using appium and java?

Tags: java, android, scroll, automation, appium

I would like to know how to scroll down to click the element in Android using appium and java?

I am having a list of elements inside "`android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`". Since it has more than 10 elements, we need to swipe the screen to see the below elements. 
Each element has same id which is "`com.osanda.exampleapp/textViewTitle`". But their texts are different like "Apple", "Orange", "Grapes"......

All I need is to scroll and click the relevant element using its text("Apple", "Orange", "Grapes".....)

I have followed many tutorials but couldn't do it properly. I have managed to scroll down the screen. But it won't work when the element is in the middle position of the scroll.

When I listed the element names it only shows the visible elements, not all elements.

```
List<WebElement> elements = androidDriver.findElementByClassName("android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView").findElements(By.id("com.osanda.exampleapp:id/textViewTitle"));
        for(WebElement element : elements) {
            System.out.println(element.getText());
        }
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I tried this solution and it is worked for me.

```
public void scrollAndClick(String visibleText) {
     androidDriver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\""+visibleText+"\").instance(0))").click();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just curious, is there a way this technique can work with xpaths as well. For instance if we replace textContains with a locator.

Comment: @KovidMehta
I think you can use the below generic function for scrolling.

`public void scrollUsingTouchActionsByElements(MobileElement startElement, MobileElement endElement) {`
        `TouchAction actions = new TouchAction(driver);`
      `actions.press(startElement).waitAction(Duration.ofSeconds(2)).moveTo(endElement).release().perform();`
`}`

Let me know if this useful to you.

Comment: it is refreshing page before searching for an element in android app.

Comment: this method scroll form down to up for search text. is there any other method to go top to down

Comment: ddjadav have you found the solution?

Answer (score 4):

Please use the code below. It will scroll till the text is visible.

```
   String uiSelector = "new UiSelector().textMatches(\"" + text
                        + "\")";

   String command = "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView("
                        + uiSelector + ");";

    driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator(command);
```

Now you could perform the click action after this.

Comment: I tried your solution for my automation script. What it does is scrolls up little bit & then scrolls down. This way it scrolls for 2-3 times but didn't reach the intended element to be visible. My app can have even 50-60 entries and there can't be more than 8-9 entries in screen at one point of time. So what you think need to be changed if the above script has to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In new versions of Appium you can use this:

```
TouchActions action = new TouchActions(driver);
action.scroll(element, 10, 100);
action.perform();
element.click();
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Had to use driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(text(\"myText"));").click();

Answer (score 1):

```
public AndroidElement ScrollToElement(String by, String using) {
    AndroidElement element = null;
    int numberOfTimes = 10;
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    int anchor = (int) (size.width / 2);
    // Swipe up to scroll down
    int startPoint = (int) (size.height - 10);
    int endPoint = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; i++) {
        try {
            new TouchAction(driver)
                .longPress(point(anchor, startPoint))
                .moveTo(point(anchor, endPoint))
                .release()
                .perform();
            element = (AndroidElement) driver.findElement(by, using);
            i = numberOfTimes;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Element not available. Scrolling (%s) times...", i + 1));
        }
    }
    return element;
}
```

In your test use as follows:
Example:
`String usingWebView = “//android.widget.TextView[@text=‘Spinner’]”;
String by = “xpath”;
MobileActions mbAct = new MobileActions(driver); //This is just a class which has above function code.
AndroidElement webViewElement = mbAct.ScrollToElement(by, usingWebView, 250);
webViewElement.click();`

Comment: what is `point` in this code?
Also 'findElement(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' has PROTECTED access in 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver'

Answer (score 0):

`findElementByAndroidUIAutomator--AndroidUiAutomater` is depriciated in latest release,

Where as Now code which is working looks like

```
MobileElement element = driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(
        "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceId(\"com.android.vending:id/tab_recycler_view\")).getChildByText("
        + "new UiSelector().className(\"android.widget.TextView\"), \"Games We Are Playing\")"));

//Perform the action on the element
element.click();
```

Comment: Lokesh, I tried your code but it scrolls the screen 1-2 Centimeter only once and finally failed to reach the expected text/element.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below while loop which looks for the contain by swiping down through the screen till the expected element appears

```
    While (driver.findElements(By.id(“id”)).size()==0){
size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.80);
int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.20);
int startx = size.width / 2;
System.out.println("starty = " + starty + " ,endy = " + endy + " , startx = " + startx);

driver.swipe(startx, starty, startx, endy, 3000);
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.swipe(startx, endy, startx, starty, 3000);
Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

once your element detected while exits and you can execute your action.

Answer (score 0):

This Works for me, scroll will stop when the text is visible. here my Text is : "Progress Bar", Just replace according to your text. it will work.

```
String scrollElement = "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text(\"Progress Bar\").instance(0))";

driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator(scrollElement).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this one

```
public void scrollAndClick(String visibleText) {
 androidDriver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator
  ("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).
   instance(0)).scrollIntoView(
  new UiSelector().textContains(\""+visibleText+
  "\").instance(0))").click();
    }
   }
```

or this one:

```
String uiSelector = "new UiSelector().textMatches
(\"" + text+ "\")";
String command = "new UiScrollable(
new UiSelector().scrollable(true).
instance(0)).scrollIntoView("+ uiSelector + ");";
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator(command);
```

It will scroll till the text is visible.